# Ultrasonic sounds on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

I know this has been asked before but that was almost a year ago so thought I would check again.

Is there a way to play sounds greater than 20,000Hz? I want to create a dog whistle app to call my dog.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but all you've done is specify the OS. What kind of hardware is involved? Hook an android up to an arduino and you can crank out whatever frequencies you want.

Comment: Cool! An app that causes bats to fly into the wall!

Comment: With the speakers that most (if not all) smartphones have, I find it highly unlikely that they can do 20,000 Hz :)

Comment: I guess the question would have suggested no other hardware other than the OS device but yes, you are right, hooking an android or iPhone up to x will do y but I meant with no other hardware involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the native sampling rate on smartphones typically is 48 or 44.1 kHz, the internal loudspeaker/earpiece component is not likely to have the frequency response curve that you'd need for your app.

Possible solutions would be to hook up something like a piezo buzzer to the 3.5mm analog stereo jack on the phone. Or if you want to completely bypass the internal DAC you could hook up an external high-quality DAC through the USB port on devices that supports it, and then hook up whatever speaker you want to the external DAC. Though unless the device supports "HD" audio (like 88 kHz or above sampling rate) you'd still have an upper bound of 24 or 22.5 kHz on the frequencies you can reproduce.